# Silverlight - Multiline textbox - Alt + Enter Issue

Tags: silverlight

I am stuck with the small issue...

I am using Silverlight.

I have a textbox with multiline property true. 
and i want the facillity that when user press "ALT + Enter" then cursor should move to the next line.

I have already set the properties like AcceptsReturn, TextWrapping. But it is not working :(

Can anyone please shed some light on this?

Thanks,
Mahesh

Here is sample code:

Style x:Key="MultilineTextBoxCellStyle" TargetType="TextBox">
            Setter Property="AcceptsReturn" Value="True"/>
            Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="Wrap"/>
            Setter Property="Height" Value="100"/>
            Setter Property="Page:MultilineTextboxScrollbar.MyVsbv" Value="Auto" />

I am giving this style to dynamic created textbox: Which is in grid view ....

dataColumn.EditorSettings = new TextBoxEditorSettings();
                        dataColumn.EditorSettings.CellEditStyle = (Style)this.Resources["MultilineTextBoxCellStyle"];

THanks,
Mahesh

Comment: Can you post the relevant XAML and code behind. You'll get more relevant answers if you do.

Answer (score 0):

Alt + Enter in a silverlight single line textbox actually makes IE 8 switch to fullscreen mode.  Also, in my book allowing Silverlight applications to override browser shortcuts would be a serious security issue...

Here's a related question:
[Override (IE7) browser keyboard handling from Silverlight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/769668/override-ie7-browser-keyboard-handling-from-silverlight)